# Issue with jsFiddle and identical code not working with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently having an with my jQuery,
Below is the code that generates a list via PHP and the list is then clickable to create a list of the sub contents of that folder.

I have a jsfiddle of this working: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4XC6a/1/)

However when run on my page it is not running; the issue seem to be replicated when selecting "No wrap - in ".

I honestly don't know anything about these 4 jsfiddle options, it works in 3 but not 4. This may have been a stupid oversight by me or I may be missing some form of critical info

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('fileServer')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") 
         && ($file != ".."))
        {
            $thelist .= '<LI id='.$file.'>'.$file.'';
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
function genCont(){
//  alert(sel + "folder selected")


//This is the alert that works in JSfiddle but not on my Rpi :(
$("#fList li").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // get id of clicked li used in below PHP
});

//future unused code, suggestion for improvement are, of course, welcome 
//var fName = sel;
<?php
if ($handle = opendir(/*not used yet*/)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") 
         && ($file != ".."))
        {
            $thelist2 .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
        }
        }

    closedir($handle);
}?>
}
</script>


<div class="fsFolder">
<ul id="fList">
<?=$thelist?>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Thank you ahead of time SO

Kris

Comment: @Sergio: If so, that's a really bad title for the question, given that the issue here is that it **does** work on jsFiddle, just not in the wild. :-)

Comment: I realize my title is poor retrospecitively as well as the jsfiddle was slightly wrong, but yes it works on jsfiddle and not on my Rpi.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :) I thought it would help OP to understand jsfiddle better. But he got good answers now so I remove my comment. Thanks for the sharp eye :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been hit by jsFiddle's ***really surprising default behavior***, which is to wrap all of your JavaScript code in a `window` `load` handler. If you look in the upper left-hand corner of the jsFiddle UI, you'll see an unlabelled drop-down box, with the value `onload` selected. The `window` `load` event happens *very late* in the page load cycle, after all HTML has been parsed, all external resources (including images) have been loaded, etc.

Just put your `script` tags at the end of your page, just above `</body>`, so that the elements they act on exist. The problem with your code is that this line:

```
$("#fList li").click(...);
```

happens *before* that element exists, because it's above it in the page source. Just put it below it in the page source.

References:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure Library engineers on when DOM elements are ready](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E/RjllWWJTXAcJ)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly the layout should be; decending order <head>CSS etc/<body> content, THEN onclick <script></body>

Is this standard or more unique to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code with doc.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){/*code*/});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#fList li").click(function () {
        alert(this.id); // get id of clicked li
    });

    //$boobies = document.getElementByID("#fList li").this.id
    $boobies = $('#fList li')[0].id;

});
```

Comment: Sorry for not fully understanding do you mean the function genContent() or just:

    $("#fList li").click(function() {
        alert(this.id); // get id of clicked li used in below PHP
    });

or is it that whole script tag?

Comment: @Ziconius check the update, and btw document.getElementByID doesn't work like jQuery $()

Comment: `ready` handlers are for libraries. There are better options if you control the location of your `script` elements.